# Redirect/Resend IP packets after WakeOnLan

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, spoofing

my old pc is playing home server now and uses a lot of energy. Therefore i'd like to suspend it, when it's not needed and wake it up when someone tries to access it.

- My plan is to notify a Raspberry Pi when the server goes sleeping.
- The Pi will grab the server's ip and wait for incomming traffic. Then
- the Pi drops the server's IP address and sends a WakeOnLan packet to the server.

As every packet sent to the RasPi would get lost, it would be great if I could get the Pi to buffer the traffic (at least to a certain level) and redirect it to the server.

Since the traffic is valid in case of TCP segment numbers, etc. it should not be a problem to simply re-send it, i think.
Only the TCP timeout might be a Problem. Is there any way to "pause" the connection for some seconds?

How can I pass the connections to the server, when it is online again?